# HTML input field entry lookahead REGEX Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, input, keyboard-events

The regex in box1 works, then I added the regex in box2 and was going to convert it to my use - it looks ahead and wont let the user enter a leading space.  When I replace the characters in parenthesis I get warnings/errors (in eclipse) - I've tried escaping the first character
but that doesn't fix it - an I having "escape" problems?  Thanks for the help!

```
if (v.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null)   works

 try     (v.match(^(?!\s)([a-zA-Z0-9 _.'"()!?&@]){1,}$) !== null)   fails
       (v.match(/^(?!\s)([a-zA-Z0-9 _.'"()!?&@]){1,}$) !== null)  fails

      errors undefined attribute name null 

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
Typical InputBox1
<input type="text" name="date"  onkeyup="var v = this.value;
if (v.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {this.value = v + '/';}
else if (v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {this.value = v + '/';}"
maxlength="10">
<br>
Typical InputBox2
<input type="text" name="date"  onkeyup="var v = this.value;
if (v.match(^(?!\s)([a-zA-Z0-9 _.'"()!?&@]){1,}$) !== null) {this.value = v + '/';}
else if (v.match(^(?!\s)([a-zA-Z0-9 _.'"()!?&@]){1,}$) !== null) {this.value = v + '/';}"
maxlength="10">

<!--   ^(?!\s)([a-zA-Z0-9 _.'"()!?&@]){1,}$    lookahead for leading blank space -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@M42 you were spot on, but I found the escape character didn't work here - seems what's expected is "HTML escape" which doesn't exist, but substituting `&quot;` or `&#34;` for that quote char at least turned the eclipse warning off. Thanks for finding the char issue.

Answer (score 0):

Escape all the double quotes in the regex.

```
(v.match(^(?!\s)([a-zA-Z0-9 _.'\"()!?&@]){1,}$) !== null)
//                      here __^
```

Comment: I tested the regex online and it seems to work fine - your suggestion didn't fix it - seems there is a lot of escaping to be done - I tried carefully but still an error

Comment: needs escaping  \  .  + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -

Comment: else if (v.match(\^\(\?\!\\s\)\(\[a\-zA\-Z0\-9 _\.'"\(\)\!\?&@\]\)\{1,\}\$) !== null) {this.value = v + '/';}"
maxlength="10">